# Printing x amounts of characters in terminal or python?

Tags: python, linux

If i need x amount of characters to test my program, is there a way of generating them quickly with terminal in linux? or in python?
for example I want to test if my program breaks when I enter 80 characters. But instead of writing 80 characters I want to be able to just generate 80 characters in terminal and then copy paste it to my program (or pipeline it etc).
I tried doing:

```
>>> for item in range (1,80):
...     print "x",
```

It works but it prints x with spaces inbetween which would be more than 80 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be 'x's? For a random string you can use this from the shell

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom count=80 bs=1
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python, the multiplication operator `*` can apply to strings.

```
print "x" * 80
```

Answer (score 3):

On the shell, you can abuse `seq`:

```
% seq -f foo -s '' 10
foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo
```

If you want your strings to be separated by newlines, using `yes` is easiest:

```
% yes
y
y
y
...
% yes foo
foo
foo
foo
...
% yes twice | head -2
twice
twice
```

Comment: The second one works, but seq gives me :

seq: format `foo' has no % directive

Comment: Aww. It works on Mac OS X for example, but I just checked on a debian machine, and GNU seq indeed wants to have a % directive in the format string. I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
print "x" * 80
```

or

```
print "".join([str(x) for x in xrange(80)])
```

this will generate long list

Answer (score 0):

you can use the * operator on a character to repeat it 80 times.  so just make a small file called "out.py" containing the line

```
print 'x' * 80
```

then write

```
$ python out.py | python prgm.py
```

in the terminal where prgm.py is the name of your python program